# Positioning Boxes evenly horizontally using Grid Layout - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have this code:

```css
.flex-container6 {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 125px;
  font-family: Archivo Narrow Regular;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container6">

        <div class="wrapper">

          <div id="firstt">1</div>
          <div id="firstt2">2</div>
          <div id="firstt3">3</div>

        </div>

      </div>
```

I gave the biggest box margins which are correct, now I'm trying to make these 3 separate boxes in the big box with 20% margins be aligned evenly horizontally. This means: Box 1 will be against left side of 20% margin and box 3 at the right side with 2nd box in the middle.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: can your please describe your question more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

In your class `.wrapper`, you can use the flexbox system, that's quit simple. Take a look and let me know if that's what you needed.

```css
.flex-container6 {

  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 125px;
  font-family: Archivo Narrow Regular;
  font-size: 33px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container6">

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div id="firstt">1</div>
    <div id="firstt2">2</div>
    <div id="firstt3">3</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the css for wrapper class like this,

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 20%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Adding `margin-left` in the wrapper class will push the first child to left (20% in this case). Then adding `justify-content: space-between` will spread the children in available width. This will make sure that there is same gap between 1-2 and 2-3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS grid:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

You can then use `grid-gap` to control the gap between the grid items.

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ for more information on CSS grid.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, You need to add just below .wrapper css. It's the most easiest and efficient way to achieve this using `display: grid;`

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

above property will make the grid area of 3 fractions and give equal width of 1 out of 3 fraction to each child grid elements. Also use `grid-column-gap: 10%;` to give 10% margin from both sides. Total 20%.

```css
.flex-container6 {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 125px;
  font-family: Archivo Narrow Regular;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10%;
}
.wrapper>div {
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container6">

        <div class="wrapper">

          <div id="firstt">1</div>
          <div id="firstt2">2</div>
          <div id="firstt3">3</div>

        </div>

      </div>
```